# How to make real-time detection of usb status by Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel VBA to implement instrument control , most of functions already done but error handling can't make well. A error condition is that removing usb without close software ( Do disconnect method and Set instrument object = nothing   )  will cause connection fail  (error message is portID already in used). I try re-plug usb or reopen VBA is not work. Are there any method can real-time monitor usb port status by VBA code ??? or any suggestion of handling this kind of running time erro.

Comment: I would imagine you would have to delve into the Windows API to get access to that. [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx) has an example of a call to the Win API (yes, that's for time zone, it's just an example of how to set up VBA for an API call). If you really want to make this work in VBA from Excel, that's most likely the way you're going to have to go.

Comment: You're looking for an event listener? Not sure about that.  But you should be able to *trap* and handle the error which arises when user remove the USB. What does your error handler look like right now?